# PHP Mysql broadcast Message System

Tags: php, mysql, message, broadcast

I'm trying to build a messaging system. The system that I create is only able to send message to a user. Trying to make a broadcast system and now I could send to multiple users. But now the problem is how I could make a notification when it's a new broadcast message, and how I could delete the broadcast message?

**NB :** When I delete the broadcast message with a user(example the user I use is 'user1'), the broadcast message will also deleted in another user account.

Can anybody help me how to solve this problem please?

**EDIT**

Here I got some table in my database

**Table Message**

```
id_message (INT(11))
to (VARCHAR(50))
from (INT(11))
title (TEXT)
user1delete (TINYINT(4))
user2delete (TINYINT(4))
```

**Table Detail_Message**

```
id_message (INT(11))
id_reply (INT(11))
from (INT(11))
message (TEXT)
user1read (TINYINT(4))
user2read (TINYINT(4))
```

**Table Broadcast_Delete_Status**

```
id_message (INT(11))
user (INT(11))
```

when the message is pointed to single user, the column 'to' in table message save the id of the recipient, and when it is a multiple or broadcast message, the column save "all user" or "all operator".

Comment: post some code you tried... and for the problem you should create diffrent instances of the message i think..

Comment: check my edit. I don't think that the database that I've create is correct. Please tell me if it still need changes.

Comment: think of it on your own.its not that difficult..

Comment: and in my PHP and mysql code, I check the user that in the SESSION, and then get all the message that pointed to the user(WHERE to='$iduser' OR to='all user'). So, when I want to delete the broadcast message, it will cause delete action in another user account.

Comment: do you have any suggestion?

Comment: you can use 3 table - 1 for messages, 1 for users and the last for sender-receiver data.

Comment: for messages table I already have it, and for user table too. My user table only save id user, username, email, and password. For the last table you've suggest, sender-reciever data, can I use my Detail_Message as sender-reciever data table?